# mod_fastcgi not working with <IfModule...> and php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, mod-fastcgi

In the primary `httpd.conf` file I have the following for loading the fastcgi module:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
```

In a different file for vhosts I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost some_ip:80>
  ServerName some_ip.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/some_ip.local
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

  <IfModule fastcgi_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
    Action application/x-httpd-php /tmp/fpm.fcgi
    FastCGIExternalServer /php5.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000
    Alias /tmp/fpm.fcgi /php5.fcgi
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I remove the `<IfModule>` check then it (fpm) works just fine.

When I add the `<IfModule>` check it does not work at all; I've tried checking against `mod_fastcgi.so` and `mod_fastcgi.c`. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it;

I had `Include conf.d/*.conf` at the top of the main `httpd.conf` file. Moved it to the bottom and now `<IfModule fastcgi_module>...</IfModule>` works as expected.